# How to make eclipse to not download XSD?

Tags: java, eclipse, download, xsd

Everytime I open file that has xsd declarations (like [Seam's components.xml](http://seamframework.org/132844.lace)) Eclipse start downloading xsd files, Seam is very modular so it uses 10 xsd files. How to make Eclipse not download those files or download them once(maybe it cant download it because the plugin is not using proxy configuration) or even download it for him at put them in some directory?

P.S. I dont know if its JBossTools specific, maybe its behavior inherited from WTP plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML Catalog should work. That is its intended function. Make sure that you are adding correct entries and including schemas that are indirectly referencing by other schemas.

When entering XSD files into the catalog, you need to know the URL by which the file will be accessed. If you enter it under a wrong URL, it will not be found in the catalog and Eclipse will access internet to try to locate it. To figure out what URL to use, look at your XML files that reference these schemas. If there is a schemaLocation attribute, that will tell you the URL to use. Otherwise, use the namespace URL.

It is also possible for a plugin to contribute entries to the XML catalog. If JBoss Tools is providing tooling for Seam, it should ideally ship XSD files it needs in the plugin and register them in the catalog automatically. You may want to open an enhancement request on JBoss Tools.

Comment: See my answer if you still have problems after using XML Catalog in Eclipse!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create catalog entry in Eclipse to reference the XSDs locally.

Window > Preferences > XML > XML Catalog

Comment: good idea, but it doesnt work. eclipse start downloading it anyway :(

Comment: ugh sorry to hear it :-( was worth a shot.  Have you tried the eclipse forums?

Answer (score 1):

They key is to use the full URL, including the XSD filename in the Key with the Namespace.  Just using the namespace doesn't work.

Open up your Eclipse preferences, go to XML Catalog and add each xsd manually, selecting it from the filesystem.

And you do not need to restart eclipse (I am using 3.6+), but you may need to rebuild your project.

You can also programmatically add one or more XSD files to your project, but that may not help you for auto-completion.

Related Eclipse plugin question:
[How to add an XSD to Eclipse catalog directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489737/how-to-add-an-xsd-to-eclipse-catalog-directly)

Comment: The linky is very very old... July 21, 2009... just saying, it might be better to quote the page in your answer to prevent link rot...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the XML Catalog as Konstantin Komissarchik proposed BUT I also had to delete the schemaLocation attributes in each `<import>`-Statement in each XSD-File. The reason is explained here http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog#FAQ

> **I've registered an XML Schema by namespace but XML files are still using the 'xsi:schemaLocation' value. Why?**
>   *An explicitly specified schema location value takes precedence over XML Catalog entries that are keyed by namespace.*

Comment: Note that XML Catalog entries can be keyed to the namespace, the schema location URL or both. If schema location is specified in the document, the lookup is done using that URL instead of the namespace, but the lookup always goes through the XML catalog.