# How to add an XSD to Eclipse catalog directly

Tags: xml, eclipse, plugins, xsd

I am developing a plugin for Eclipse, one of the features is to be able to edit XML. In order to do that I have to add the XSD in Eclipse catalog. 
Is there an easy way to add an XSD to Eclipse catalog directly (I mean directly through code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.catalogContributions` extension point (this requires that you have the Web Tools (WST) component of Eclipse installed.

The following is the contribution made by the `org.eclipse.wst.xsd.core` plugin:

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.catalogContributions">
    <catalogContribution id="default">
        <uri
             name="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             uri="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" />
        <system
             systemId="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"
             uri="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>             
   </catalogContribution>
</extension>
```